# Установка по нескольким путям с помощью qmake

Tags: qt, makefile, qmake

У меня есть несколько библиотек, имеющих зависимости между собой, и один проект, зависящий от этих библиотек. Сборка организована с помощью qmake.

Хочется обеспечить автоматическое размещение после сборки бинарных файлов этих библиотек (кроссплатформенно, для windows и unix) в путях, где их ожидают зависимые проекты. Нужна поддержка относительных путей.

Как я выяснил, qmake может делать установку по указанному пути таким образом:

```
target.path=$${PWD}/../relative/path/to/install
INSTALLS+=target
```

Но проблема в том, что задать несколько путей для `target` (как и `dlltarget`) невозможно - в результате qmake генерирует Makefile, в котором получаются переназначенные цели, в итоге используется только один путь (последний указанный). То есть, единственным путем установки проблема решается, а с несколькими - нет.

Как решить проблему через qmake?

**UPD**

Мой вариант решения по ответу @JK_Action выглядит следующим образом:

```
target1.path=$${PWD}/../relative/install/path/for/depependend/project/1
unix:target1.files=$${DESTDIR}/*.so*
win32:target1.files=$${DESTDIR}/*.dll

target2.path=$${PWD}/../relative/install/path/for/depependend/project/2
unix:target2.files=$${DESTDIR}/*.so*
win32:target2.files=$${DESTDIR}/*.dll

target3.path=$${PWD}/../relative/install/path/for/depependend/project/3
unix:target3.files=$${DESTDIR}/*.so*
win32:target3.files=$${DESTDIR}/*.dll

INSTALLS += target1 target2 target3
```

Comment: Основной проект и проект либ организован шаблоном SUBDIRS?

Comment: Нет, сейчас они в разных проектных файлах. Предполагается, что основной проект использует библиотеки в виде заголовочных и бинарных файлов, проектные файлы не включаются.

Comment: Я пробовал через QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS, создавая доп.цели, но не нашел, как правильно задать команды `newtarget.commands` для установки (как достать имена скомпилированных бинарных файлов для передачи, например, в `cp` для `unix{ ... }`  или `copy` для `win32{ ... }`).

Comment: Как убрать подсветку синтаксиса здесь? После /* текст явно воспринят как комментарий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я имею похожую проблему с зависимостями библиотек. На глаза попадался механизм разруливания зависимостей http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html. Увы руки так и не дошли с ним разобраться.
Временное решение валю все в одну диру для плаформы, для этого в mkspec дописываю переменные:

```
PLATFORM=x64
INSTALL_PATH=/path/to/install/$$PLATFORM.
```

Про два пути не очень понял. Вы можете в INSTALL накидать кучу таргетов:

```
target1.files=$$TARGET
target1.path=$$INSTALL_PATH/bin

target2.files=$$TARGET
target2.path=$$INSTALL_PATH/lib

target3.files=<dll?>
target3.path=$$INSTALL_PATH/lib

INSTALL += target1 target2 target3
```

Comment: Ваш совет сработал, странно, я вроде бы пробовал так же, но обламывался, подозреваю, что потому, что использовал помимо target1 еще и просто target, а оно, вероятно, завязывалось на исходный проект. В общем, мое решение выглядит так: `target1.path=$${PWD}/../relative/install/path/1
unix:target1.files=$${DESTDIR}/*.so*
win32:target1.files=$${DESTDIR}/*.dll

target2.path=$${PWD}/../relative/install/path/2
unix:target2.files=$${DESTDIR}/*.so*
win32:target2.files=$${DESTDIR}/*.dll

INSTALLS += target1 target2`